# iPhone autofill passwords

Tags: html, xhtml, iphone

I can't get my iPhone to remember my username and password for the login to my website. The controls I currently have are:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
<select>
    <option value="1">option1</option>
    <option value="2">option2</option>
</select
<input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" id="rememberMe" />
<input type="button" value="Login" />
```

When the select is removed, it all works magically. Is there a way to declare / give safari extra hints that this is a logon page?

Comment: Close vote, belongs on superuser? I don't see why html questions belong on a user site. I'm actually wondering how the HTML should be changed in a way that iPhone offers to save the password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tested with my iPhone and some test page with the following content makes the iPhone ask whether it should save the password and remember it the next time I visit the page.

`x.html`

```
<form action="x.html" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
  <select>
    <option value="1">option1</option>
    <option value="2">option2</option>
  </select>
  <input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" id="rememberMe" />
  <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

So basically it's the same as yours except that the button is of type "submit" instead of "button" and that there are form tags around the whole code snippet.

Comment: Thanks, I'll set up a test page, and see what happens, I'll keep you posted. Weird that it works though

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to look at the new iOS 8 feature to share passwords between Safari and apps:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/SharedWebCredentialsRef/
- http://www.raywenderlich.com/90978/secure-passwords-with-safari-autofill-ios-8

Comment: You should share here what you think is relevant from the given articles.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's your actual HTML or what that is, but if that's the html I can see why it wouldn't work.  First thing you probably want to add are closing tags.

```
<input type="text"></input>
<input type="password"></input>
<select></select>
<input type="checkbox"></input>
<input type="button"></input>
```

Comment: I updated the HTML to be more correct/complete, I was in a bit of a hurry when creating the question, sorry about that. The idea is that when the dropdown/select is added, the iPhone stops offering to save credentials, because it probably thinks it's no longer a login form, but a regular form.

Comment: Depending on the DTD, the closing </input> might not be necessary for it to be valid code. In XHTML, <input ... /> is valid.

I don't know if the iPhone's autofill cares one way or the other. But in terms of valid code, inputs don't need closing tage.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can try is to to add an ID and/or a name to the <select> tag.